# UWP C# MVVM clock example

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I am trying to start by looking at a simple clock example.
i am wondering how to I convert a normal clock to MVVM.
Can someone help?
Thanks.

```
private void startClock()
    {
        currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        DispatcherTimer clocktimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        clocktimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        clocktimer.Tick += Clocktimer_Tick;
        clocktimer.Start();
    }

    private void Clocktimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        updateTimeDisplay(currentTime);
    }

    private void updateTimeDisplay(DateTime time)
    {
        Time.Text = time.ToString(@"HH\:mm");
        Sec.Text = time.ToString(@"ss");
        Date.Text = time.ToString(@"ddd  dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
```

**Update**
I can't post more codes as the system flagged and unable to post.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP C# MVVM clock example

You could make string property in the viewmode and bind it with your textblock in the xaml. When you update the this property, it will notify ui update.

For example:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        startClock();
    }

    private DateTime _currentTime;
    private void startClock()
    {
        _currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        DispatcherTimer clocktimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        clocktimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        clocktimer.Tick += Clocktimer_Tick;
        clocktimer.Start();
    }

    private void Clocktimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        _currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        updateTimeDisplay(_currentTime);
    }

    private void updateTimeDisplay(DateTime time)
    {
        Time = time.ToString(@"HH:mm:ss");
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private string _time;
    public string Time
    {
        get
        {
            return _time;
        }
        set
        {
            _time = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml code**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="Time"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="25"
        Text="{Binding Time}"
        TextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

For detail mvvm design, please refer [data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) document.

Comment: it works.. thanks! It gives me a better picture now. I will be looking into MVVM `mediaplayer` and see how it plays out.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

View model will be something like this:

```
public class ClockViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ClockViewModel()
    {
        var _ = UpdateCurrentDateTimeAsync();
    }

    public DateTime? CurrentDateTime { get; private set; }

    private async Task UpdateCurrentDateTimeAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentDateTime));

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Just set it as the `DataContext` of your view and bind some visual (e.g. `TextBox`) to `CurrentDateTime` property. `ViewModelBase` is a very basic `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Comment: Can i know where do i place `startclock`? as the app starts the clock will start ..
as i am trying to grasp the concept.

Comment: @mylim: `ClockViewModel` constructor starts the clock. First you create the view, then you create view model instance, then you assign the latter to view's `DataContext`. Thats all - since this is MVVM, view doesn't contain any `startClock`, timers, etc.

Comment: I tested the code it loaded the correct `DateTime` .. however, the `tick` didn't occur every second to update the seconds... it just freeze there..

Comment: This code works fine - in fact, I've created simple WPF app to type it. I suspect, that you tested a little modified code :) So, it's better to show it.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=RootViewModel.CurrentDateTime}" />`
i place the code in my rootviewmodel
did i bind it correctly?

Comment: @mylim: the binding is OK. Did you modify the view model itself? I mean, if you will remove `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentDateTime));`, the binding will update `TextBox.Text` just once.

Comment: my viewmodel has `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of `ViewModelBase` ... as i was testing on some MVVM `button` ..

Comment: @mylim: could you post the current version of code in the question?

Comment: I have posted my code as a picture as i was unable to add more code to my post. I set breakpoint at the `Task` it did stop there every 1000ms ... however it just didn't update to XAML.

Comment: @mylim, I have post uwp code above, does it work?

Comment: @Dennis i didn't define datacontext earlier